# How do I get this post params id in this route path?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

Is this possible? I am still learning in this journey. So, I am trying to figure out if this is possible to get. I am building a blog using node.js, mongodb, mongoose and expressjs.
I have a route path like this:

```
 const router = require("express").Router()
 const Comment = require("../models/Comment")
 const Post = require("../models/Post");
  router.delete("/posts/:id/comment/:id", async (req, res) =>{
    
 
 }
```

So, basically, we want to create a comment in this path and under this posts's id.

So, can I get the post's id? I mean, can I get the id of the post on which this comment is made? I can get the params id of the comment but I don't know how to get the posts/id.
I did something like this:

```
const post = Post.findById(req.params.id) this didnt get the post.

const comment = Comment.findbyId(req.params.id) this found the comment id.
```

If this is possible, kindly tell me how to. If it is not possible, kindly provide me with an alternative way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, you use same name for both route parameters (`:id`), so express router can't distinguish if you want post `:id` or comment `:id`. Rename `/posts/:id/comment/:id` to something like `/posts/:postID/comment/:commentID` and then both parameters will be available in your code as `req.params.postID` and `req.params.commentID`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `id` both for post id and comment id.  `req.params` will only get that latter `id`,  which probably isn't something you want. Instead, you could differentiate these id-s semantically and use more clear names for them. For example:

```
router.delete("/posts/:post_id/comment/:comment_id", async (req, res) =>{
   //your code
}
```

Comment: beat me to it :D

Comment: :D a matter of seconds